# Wait for the listener in do... while GUI

Tags: java, events, while-loop, listener, wait

I create a program for Random processes(such 2+2 , 14/2 etc).

I try to create a GUI. I have 5 buttons(Add for Add, Div for the divide etc) When the user click on Add button i send a message to JTextArea to add a message:

2 + 4 =

(Or other random numbers)

I have a JTextField that the user can write the answer. So if he write 6 a success message appears to JText area(the same if he put wrong answer but a failure message) and 2 other Random numbers too, so:

2+4 = 6

Yes!

3+4 =

And continues until the method c.isOverLimit() returns true(After 10 processes).

```
int x = 10;

do {
    String string = String.format("%d %s %d =", p.getNumber1(),
                                  p.getOperator(), p.getNumber2());
    writeMessage(string);
    textField.addActionListener(
    new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                p.checkAnswer(Double.parseDouble(e.getActionCommand()));
                writeMessage(p.getMessage(Double.parseDouble(
                                              e.getActionCommand())));
                textField.setText("");
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    );
    c = Proccess.getCounter();
    x--;
}
while (x != 0);
```

My problem is that when i push the Add Button i have this output:

4+3=

4+3=

4+3=

4+3=

4+3=

4+3=

4+3=

4+3=

4+3=

4+3=

The wrong is that the do...while runs 10 times and doesn't stop for the user's answers. Dont
pay attention on the methods i use. My program runs correctly in console program so my fault is in the while...do

Sorry for my English. Thank you!

Comment: It seems you don't understand how events work. Why do you add the same listener 10 times to the text field? You don't have to wait for a listener. The listener will be called by Swing when the user presses enter in the text field.

Answer (score 0):

Counting the number of calls should be done in the `actionPerformed` method. Remove the `do...while` loop and use this instead:

```
int x = 10;
textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if (x >= 0) {
            try {
                p.checkAnswer(Double.parseDouble(e.getActionCommand()));
                writeMessage(p.getMessage(Double.parseDouble(e.getActionCommand())));
                textField.setText("");
            } catch(Exception ex){
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
            x--;
        } else {
            // quit, or whatever you want to do
        }
    }
});
```